# error qccures after creating new project in android

Tags: android

i am new in android when i create a new project using android application project following error occurs.I tried to rename package but not working also tried to refresh and restart eclipse but not working.[image: errors occur after creating project]

[image: error after import com.example.tablelayoutonly.R]
[image: activity_main]

Comment: there is no error in resource files. And when i import packagename.R thre is another error occur to create classR

Comment: @seema `import com.example.tablelayoutonly.R;` try this

Comment: @Brontok no, still have same errors

Comment: @Raghunandan i import same package

Comment: @seema then there are errors in your resource files fix them first. what do you mean by import same package?

Comment: Can you upload the `activity_mail.xml` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be like,There are some bad stuff in the resource folder,like unformatted image in drawable(imagename used in drawable should contain only small letters numbers or underscore) or something like that.Then remove android.R from import section.After that clean the whole project and check

Answer (score 0):

Remove `import android.R` and use your layout import.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `import andorid.R` and check if you have errors in your resource files. If you have errors fix them. Clean and Build your project.

Import `R` like this `import com.example.tablelayoutonly.R;`

Answer (score 0):

You should follow these steps:

1 - Check If activity_main.xml exists in res/layout folder

2 - check If man.xml exists in res/menu folder

3 - Change the name of your package automatically you should change it also in your AndroidManifest file

4 - drop the line import android.R; because with that import you oblige you app to use default android layout instead of yours.

Comment: if i am not import  import android.R; then error occur ,how to fix error

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's error in android sdk (file missing) so you need to download new sdk and try again. After that clean  your project and fix by right click on your project Android Tools -> fix project properties